# Vue 3 - nested v-if

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How to use v-if when an array is nested?

I tried

```
<div v-for="comment in project.comments.project_comments" v-if="project.comments.project_comments" class="card shadow border-start-warning py-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><span>{{comment.comment_body}}</span></div>
    </div
<div v-else>
    No commnets
</div>
```

but i got error $data.project.comments is undefined

my output from the backend

```
"comments": {
    "id": 2,
    "project_comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "comment_body": "Hi comment",
            "comment_date_add": "26.08.2022 14:22",
            "approved_comment": true
        }
    ],
    "project_comments_name": "test1"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `project.comments.project_comments` is not assigned until after an API call is complete you will encounter an error because the `v-if` runs on component creation before the API call has a chance to finish.  If you update your v-if to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) the v-if will return false if any part of `project.comments.project_comments` does not yet exist:

```
v-if="project?.comments?.project_comments"
```

Answer (score 1):

`v-if` work while each iteration of the loop. You need to check `project.comments.project_comments` on parent element.

For example like this

```
  <template v-if="project.comments.project_comments">
    <div v-for="comment in project.comments.project_comments" class="card shadow border-start-warning py-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><span>{{comment.comment_body}}</span></div>
      </div
    </div>
  </template>
  <div v-else>
    No commnets
  </div>
```